# Findingt variables for configuring app for AzureAD authentication

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Trying to configure an app to authenticate with AzureAD. In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#basics-of-registering-an-application-in-azure-ad) it says i will need following information:

- APPLICATION ID URI
- REPLY URL
- REDIRECT URL:
- APPLICATION ID:
- KEY

Im not sure what these are refering to or where to get them. This is what i found so far looking in the apps configuration and the apps settings in Azure. I find that the variables i find are not really named the same as in the artcle:

> APPLICATION ID URI:
>   (URL i azure portal)https://myAzureSite.azurewebsites.net (ISSUER URL
>   i azure portal)
>   https://sts.windows.net/*******-****-4076-8aaf-********/
>
> REPLY URL:  (Base Url i appsettings)/signin-oidc
>
> REDIRECT URL: (Base Url i appsettings)/signin-oidc
>
> APPLICATION ID: (Client ID i appsettings)
>   *******-f3a8-4e5c-b42b-******* (Subscription ID i azure portal) *******--1b0a-474b-8b03-******* Client ID i azure portal) *******--fd5f-400f-ba5b-*******
>
> KEY:  (Client Secret i appsettings)
>   f***********************************A=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application ID URI you can find from Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your app -> Properties.
This is mainly needed if your app is an API, it is used by a caller to get tokens for it.
One is generated by default, and looks like this:

```
https://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/guid-here
```

Reply URL and Redirect URL mean the same thing.
That should be in the same place except under Reply URLs.
This is the URL where Azure AD should return the user after authentication.

Application Id is found in the app registration under Properties or the main blade. It's also called the client id sometimes.
It's a GUID. But not the Object Id, that's different.

Key is a client secret configured under Keys in the app registration.

Comment: Actually, it should be `Redirect URI`,**a unique identifier** to which Azure AD will redirect the user-agent in an OAuth 2.0 request,not `Redirect URL`. Generally in Azure, it can be same as Reply URL.

Comment: Yeah, if we are technical, it's a URI :D